# Identify SAS ports on mainboard

Tags: sas

Can someone help me identify those 4 ports (left to the "CPU2" sign in the yellow box), J_STORAGE_M1 through J_STORAGE_M4?

[image: Dell R640 motherboard]

The [mainboard docs](https://qrl.dell.com/Files/en-us/html/Manuals/R640/System%20Board%20Connectors=GUID-64A0A936-F24C-4490-B929-FC2C2B3E4A1B=1=en-us=.html) label them just "SAS connector". but what kind of SAS connector is that?

Comment: I don't have ant answer, but I've seen some recent IBM hard drives described as 10,000 RPM SAS drives.